# Rosalind's 3rd problem in Scheme

Tags: beginner, scheme, bioinformatics

I have an imperative programming background and I've decided to study functional programming by applying it to problems found on sites such as Project Euler and Rosalind. My language of choice is Scheme (I use CHICKEN). As can be seen, I'm only starting out.

This is about the 3rd problem found on Rosalind, that goes like [this](http://rosalind.info/problems/revc/):

> In DNA strings, symbols 'A' and 'T' are complements of each other, as
>   are 'C' and 'G'.
>
> The reverse complement of a DNA string s is the string sc formed by
>   reversing the symbols of s, then taking the complement of each symbol
>   (e.g., the reverse complement of "GTCA" is "TGAC").
>
> Given: A DNA string s of length at most 1000 bp.
>
> Return: The reverse complement sc of s.

Here's my code, which solves the problem:

```lisp
(define (complement-of char)
  (cond
    ((eq? char #\A)
     #\T)
    ((eq? char #\T)
     #\A)
    ((eq? char #\C)
     #\G)
    ((eq? char #\G)
     #\C)
    (else
      char)))

(define (apply-complements dna-string)
  (reverse-list->string 
    (map complement-of 
     (string->list dna-string))))

(define (solve-problem infile-name outfile-name)
  (let ((outfile-port (open-output-file outfile-name))
        (infile-port (open-input-file infile-name)))
    (begin
      (write-line 
         (apply-complements (read-line infile-port)) outfile-port)
      (close-output-port outfile-port))))
```

Is there a nicer way to write `complement-of`? Perhaps something like a dictionary, or would that be too much work in this particular case?

Is `solve-problem` there appropriate from a style POV, or is this more appropriate?

```lisp
(define (solve-problem infile-name outfile-name)
  (let ((outfile-port (open-output-file outfile-name))
        (infile-port (open-input-file infile-name)))
    (begin
      (write-line 
         (apply-complements 
           (read-line infile-port)) 
         outfile-port)
      (close-output-port outfile-port))))
```

Also, is there a way to avoid using `begin` and still make things look readable? The only idea that comes to mind is extracting a function and through recursion decide whether or not it writes to the file, or closes it. But that feels hardly intuitive.

Finally, I'd like to hear of any other issues my code has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `complement-of`

The nicer way to write `complement-of` is with `case` instead of `cond`:

```
(case char
  ((#\A) #\T)
  ((#\T) #\A)
  ((#\C) #\G)
  ((#\G) #\C)
  (else char))
```

Function names generally shouldn't end in `-of`. (That's a way to pronounce function call, but it's not part of the name.) `complement` is enough. (Although some Schemes have a predefined function by that name, and it would be nice to not collide with it.)

Beware of `eq?` — it's not reliable on characters. (It's the equivalent of Java's `==` on `Character`). Use `eqv?` instead unless you know what you're doing. (`case` uses `eqv?` internally.)

#### `apply-complements`

You can simplify `apply-complements` by using one of Chicken's libraries: `(use (srfi 13))` to get `string-map`, which is like `map` but saves you having to convert to a list. That plus `string-reverse` makes `apply-complements` easy.

...but I wouldn't call it `apply-complements`, because that sounds like a reference to the `apply` function. It returns the reverse complement of its argument, so that should be its name: `reverse-complement`.

If you want to make it faster, try the imperative approach: allocate a string with `make-string`, loop with `do` and `string-set!`. (It's useful to know how to write imperative code, even in functional languages.)

#### `solve-problem`

`solve-problem` has a very ordinary bug: you forgot to close the input port. :) Fortunately, there are functions that do this automatically so you don't have to remember: `call-with-input-file` and `call-with-output-file`. They're also safer, because they close the ports on nonlocal exits like exceptions.

The body of a `let` is an implicit `begin`, so the `begin` in `solve-problem` is not needed.

Formatting: when a function call is split across multiple lines, the arguments are usually aligned, like this:

```
(write-line (apply-complements (read-line infile-port))
            outfile-port)
```

`solve-problem` has a vague name. How about a description of what it does, such as `reverse-complement-file`? (Names are the best comments.)

...however, `reverse-complement` is only one of many operations you might want to apply to a file this way. I'd probably write it as a general-purpose `transform-file` that takes the operation as a parameter: `(transform-file reverse-complement src dest)`. Or I'd write it as two separate operations for reading and writing, since they're often useful separately. (I'd also use `read-string` and `write-string` instead of `read-line` and `write-line`, so they'd work on files of more than one line.)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a complete rundown to me :) Good point at the "of" bit in the function call. Since I read & process maths in Romanian it never occurred to me before but I'll definitely keep it in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary/hash but for 4 choices it is overkill.

In my opinion, `apply-compliments` is just the map over `compliment-of`. I would call the core function `reverse-compliment`. As an aside, if I read the problem description correctly you reverse the string and then apply the compliments but you appear to be complimenting and then reversing. Functionally it does not matter of course.

My scheme is a little rusty to be honest, but I think since you are in a `let` form you do not need the `begin`.

I would have laid out `solve-problem` the same way.